# Concatenate Regex.Matches to a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq, c#-4.0

I have a string like this:

```
string str = "key1=1;main.key=go1;main.test=go2;key2=2;x=y;main.go23=go23;main.go24=test24";
```

I use this pattern to extract all substrings that starts with `main.`:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("main.[^=]+=[^=;]+");       
MatchCollection matchCollection = regex.Matches(str);
```

To concatenate the MatchCollection, I have tried this:

```
string flatchain = string.Empty;
foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
{
    flatchain = flatchain +";"+ m.Value; 
}
```

Is there a better way to do it using LINQ?

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can  try to convert your result into an array and apply the `string.Join` to put your string in flat 
here  you must specify  the `Match` type explicitly as the `MatchCollection` is a `non-generic IEnumerable` type

```
  var toarray = from Match match in matchCollection select match.Value;
                string newflatChain = string.Join(";", toarray);
```

or  if you want just one line you can do it like  the following

```
string newflatChain = string.Join(";", from Match match in matchCollection select match.Value);
```

Answer (score 11):

As a one-liner, this would be

```
var flatchain = string.Join(";", matchCollection.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));
```

The reason for the cast is that a MatchCollection does only implement the old not generic IEnumerable version.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use LINQs `Aggregate`. For example:

```
var strIn = "key1=1;main.key=go1;main.test=go2;key2=2;x=y;main.go23=go23;main.go24=test24";

var strOut = Regex
             .Matches(str, "(main.[^=]+=[^=;]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline)
             .Cast<Match>()
             .Select(c => c.Value)
             .Aggregate(( a, b ) => a + ";" + b);
```

*Note:* Since the `Match` property `Value` has a private setter, LINQs `Select` cannot be bypassed as we need to assign a string in Aggregate's lambda expression.